# Fill area between two lines and curves

Tags: tikz-pgf, fillbetween

I would like to fill the area as marked in the picture (blue color), I didn't manage to do so, this is my attempt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc, pgfplots.fillbetween}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=0.7]

\coordinate (O) at (-10,0) ;
\coordinate (A) at (-8.5,1.5) {};
\coordinate (B) at (3,2.5) {};
\coordinate (end) at (6,3.7) {};
\draw[name path=curve,thick] (3.5,0) .. controls (3.5,5) and (4.5,6.5) .. (end);
\path[name path=line1,thick] (4.7,0) --+ (90:6);
\path[name path=line2,thick] (end) --+ (160:6);
\draw[thick,name path=line3] (O) to [out=15,in=170,thick](3.5,0);
\path [name intersections={of=curve and line1,by=E}];
\path [name intersections={of=curve and line2,by=Q}];
\draw[thick,name path=line5] (end)--(Q);
\draw[thick,name path=line4] (O) to [out=90,in=170](E);
\tikzfillbetween[of=line3 and line4]{ball color=gray!50,opacity=0.1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]

\coordinate (O) at (-10,0);
\coordinate (end) at (6,3.7);

\path[name path=curve1] (3.5,0) .. controls (3.5,5) and (4.5,6.5) .. (end);
\path[name path=curve2] (O) to[out=15, in=170] (3.5,0);
\path[name path=line1] (4.7,0) -- +(90:6);
\path[name path=line2] (end) -- +(160:6);

\path[name intersections={of=curve1 and line1, by=E}];
\path[name path=curve3] (O) to[out=90, in=170] (E);

\path[name path=curve4, 
    intersection segments={of=curve2 and curve3, sequence={L* -- R*[reverse]}}];
\fill[gray, draw=black, thick, 
    intersection segments={of=curve1 and curve4, sequence={R1 -- L2 -- R3}}] -- cycle;

\fill[gray!50, draw=black, thick, 
    intersection segments={of=curve1 and line2, sequence={L2 -- R2}}] -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Some remarks:

- As already stated as comment in your code, `pgfplots` loads `tikz` already. There is no need therefore to load it again. I also removed the other packages, libraries, macros and options from the code that are not necessary for this example.
- The coordinates `A` and `B` are not used in your code and I removed them.
- A `\coordinate` does not take an argument in curly braces `{}` (unline a `\node`).
- The option `thick` only has an effect on a `\path` together with the option `draw`.
- I actually only draw and fill the paths at the very end. Hence, the code to draw the short line from `end` to `Q` is no more necessary.
- I renamed the paths, but feel free to use other names.

Comment: Very nice @JasberHabicht  For me `sequence` and `intersection segments` are new commands.